# Two-variable limits along paths $x\mapsto (x, mx^n)$ at the origin

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Here is an interesting problem that I came across recently --

> Construct a map $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ with
> $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)\\} f(x,y) = 0$
> along all paths $y=y(x)$ with $y(x) = mx^n$, where $m\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and such that $\lim_{{\bf x}\to{\bf 0}} f({\bf x})$ does not exist.

This is my attempt. Define $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by
$$f(x,y) = \begin{cases}\: |x|^{|y|}-1, &\text{$(x,y)\not=(0,0)$} \\ \:0, &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$
We claim that $f$ is a map with the desired properties.

We first observe that the limit $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)\\} f(x,y)$ along a path of the form $t\mapsto(t, mt^n)$ is given by
$$\ell(m,n):=\lim_{t\to0}\:\Big(|t|^{|mt^n|}-1\Big)=\bigg\{\lim_{t\to0}\:\exp\Big(|m||t|^n\ln|t|\Big)\bigg\}-1. \tag{1}$$
We now show that $\ell(m,n)=0$ for all $m\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$. To this end, we compute $\lim_{t\to 0}\:|t|^n\ln|t|$. We have
$$\lim_{t\to 0}\:|t|^n\ln|t|=\lim_{t\to 0^+}\:t^n\ln t=-\lim_{x\to+\infty}xe^{-nx}=0,$$
where the second equality follows after setting $t=e^{-x}$, and the third follows after an application of L'Hopital's rule.
Since $x\mapsto \exp(x)$ is continuous at $x=0$ and the limit $\lim_{t\to 0}|mt^n|\ln|t|=0$, we can push the limit in $(1)$ inside the exponential. It follows that
$$\ell(m,n)=0\:\:\text{ for all }m\in \mathbb{R}\text{ and }n\in\mathbb{N},$$
as desired. Now, it remains to show that $f$ does not approach a limit at the origin. Indeed, consider the path $t\mapsto (e^{-1/|t|},t)$. This path approaches $(0,0)$ as $t\to 0$ (and so do the paths $t\mapsto (t,mt^n)$). Along this path, the limit of $f$ at the origin is
$$\lim_{t\to0}\: f(e^{-1/|t|},t)=e^{-1}-1\not=0.$$
Thus, $\lim_{{\bf x}\to 0}f({\bf x})$ does not exist.

Is this construction correct? I am also looking for more such constructions. Thanks!

Comment: See my answer to [Multivariable limits](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/1891/745). Incidentally, I was unaware of this example when I made it up back in the late 1990s, but I've seen occasional mentions of it since then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A general construction
$$f(x,y):=y|x|^{\epsilon-1}g(x)\,,$$
where $\epsilon\in(0,1)$ and $g$ is a bounded function with no limit as $x\to 0$ satisfies the hypothesis of your problem but $f(x,|x|^{1-\epsilon})$ does not converge as $x\to 0$.